# Masjid Al Aqsa was the first qibla, and mentioned in the quran, so why is Medina more holy

Tags: islamic-basis, masjid

I love the prophet more than anyone else, and I know that Medina is very holy and I am not trying to discredit it, and I know that Al Aqsa cannot be more holy than the Kaaba, but why is Medina considered more precious than Al Aqsa. Allah made Al Aqsa the first qibla and mentioned "blessing its surroundings" in the quran. I am trying to learn not to criticise.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think Muslims prayed facing Aqsa initially in an attempt to build relationships with the Jews.

Answer (score 2):

Assalamualaikum! The importance of Medina can be derived from the facts given below:

1. The first mosque of Islam was built over there
2. The mosque of the Prophet (Sm.) ,i.e. the Masjid al Nababi was also built there
3. Rasulullah (Sm.) rests in peace there.

The 3rd one is the main reason why Medina is more important than Al-Aqsa and if you want to know the facts why logically also Medinah stands with more importance, jump to this [***article.***](https://www.searchtruth.com/book_display.php?book=30&translator=1)

A summary of this article is that the prophet has made Medinah a Holy place, a Haram place for bloodshed, and also he (Sm.) has declared that Dajjal and Plague won't enter Medinah. So, regarding that , we do not see the same to Masjid al Aqsa. and Remember, both Mekka and Medinah are places, while Al-Aqsa is a Mosque. Anyways, people love Medinah as Our Prophet (Sm.) used to love it and due to the fact that it is the Prophet's City.

Regarding to your logic that Masjid al-aqsa has been mentioned itn Al-Quran, Masjid al Quba, the first mosque of Islam situated in Medinah has also been mentioned in the Quran as following:

The virtue of Masjid Qubas is mentioned in the following Quranic verse in Surah Taubah: “…certainly a masjid founded on piety from the very first day is more deserving that you should stand in it…” [9:108]

Jazakallahu Khairun!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the many supplications of the Prophet Sallallaahualaihiwasallam صلى الله عليه وسلم! He loved Madina and its people that he decided to die there! In a narration in Sahih Muslim, he said: (O Allah makes us love Madina as much as Makkah or even more!)

So it is even permissible to love Madina more than Makkah! It is the place where Islam was established!

Allah knows best